# Dynamic programming - board with multiplier

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I got quite standard DP problem - board `n`x`n` with integers, all positive. I want to start somewhere in the first row, end somewhere in the last row and accumulate as much sum as possible. From field `(i,j)` I can go to fields `(i+1, j-1)`, `(i+1, j)`, `(i+1, j+1)`. 
That's quite standard DP problem. But we add one thing - there can be an asterisk on the field, instead of the number. If we meet the asterisk, then we got `0` points from it, but we increase multiplier by `1`. All numbers we collect later during our traversal are multiplied by `multiplier`.
I can't find out how to solve this problem with that multiplier thing. I assume that's still a DP problem - but how to get the equations right for it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So, the multiplier only affects the number that are encountered _later_ is this correct? Then why not just start from the last row and work your way backwards?

Comment: That's right, only later.

Comment: You should post a (small) example grid and the best solution for that grid.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use DP, but you have to keep track of two values: The "base" value, i.e. without any multipliers applied to it, and the "effective" value, i.e. with multipliers. You work your way backwards through the grid, starting in the previous-to-last row, get the three "adjacent" cells in the row after that (the possible "next" cells on the path), and just pick the one with the highest value.

If the current cell is a `*`, you get the cell where `base + effective` is maximal, otherwise you just get the one where the `effective` score is highest.

Here's an example implementation in Python. Note that instead of `*` I'm just using `0` for multipliers, and I'm looping the grid in order instead of in reverse, just because it's more convenient.

```py
import random

size = 5
grid = [[random.randint(0, 5) for _ in range(size)] for _ in range(size)]
print(*grid, sep="\n")

# first value is base score, second is effective score (with multiplier)
solution = [[(x, x) for x in row] for row in grid]

for i in range(1, size):
    for k in range(size):
        # the 2 or 3 values in the previous line
        prev_values = solution[i-1][max(0, k-1):k+2]
        val = grid[i][k]
        if val == 0:
            # multiply
            base, mult = max(prev_values, key=lambda t: t[0] + t[1])
            solution[i][k] = (base, base + mult)
        else:
            # add
            base, mult = max(prev_values, key=lambda t: t[1])
            solution[i][k] = (val + base, val + mult)

print(*solution, sep="\n")
print(max(solution[-1], key=lambda t: t[1]))
```

Example: The random 5x5 grid, with `0` corresponding to `*`:

```
[4, 4, 1, 2, 1]
[2, 0, 3, 2, 0]
[5, 1, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 0, 2, 4, 1]
[1, 0, 5, 2, 0]
```

The final `solution` grid with base values and effective values:

```
[( 4,  4), ( 4,  4), ( 1,  1), ( 2,  2), ( 1,  1)]
[( 6,  6), ( 4,  8), ( 7,  7), ( 4,  4), ( 2,  4)]
[( 9, 13), ( 5,  9), ( 7, 11), (11, 11), ( 9,  9)]
[( 9, 22), ( 9, 22), ( 9, 13), (11, 15), (12, 12)]
[(10, 23), ( 9, 31), (14, 27), (13, 17), (11, 26)]
```

Thus, the best solution for this grid is `31` from `(9, 31)`. Working backwards through the grid `solution` grid, this corresponds to the path `0-0-5-0-4`, i.e. `3*5 + 4*4 = 31`, as there are 2 `*` before the `5`, and 3 `*` before the `4`.

Comment: I would have suggested going forward traversing a 3-d space of `(i, j, mult)` but this is clearly better.  (Though my version requires less cleverness.)

Comment: @btilly I'm not at all sure that this is correct in all cases. If you were already close to a solution on your own, please continue and let's compare results.

Comment: One suggestion the multiplier is supposed to get multiplied instead of addition, I guess. Saying this based on the question.

Comment: @zenwraight Well, it _is_ multiplying by repeated addition. See the example at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @tobias_k I wasn't so far as to write any code. :-)  But the idea is simple.  Just keep your data in a dictionary whose keys are tuples that include both where you are and state.  Then it is a straightforward DP forward.